# Scheme let bound statements

Tags: scheme, racket

The following is in my class notes for Scheme:

```
(let ((x 2) (y 3))
  (let ((x 7) (z (+ x y)))
    (* z x)))
```

The answer yields 35. Can someone explain this to me?
So on the 2nd line z(+x y) the x value seems to be 2 but after that (* z x) the x value is 7? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easier way to explain this is by looking at let as syntax sugar for anonymous procedure calls.

```
(let ((x 2) (y 3))
  (let ((x 7) (z (+ x y)))
    (* z x)))
```

Is the same as:

```
((lambda (x y)
   ((lambda (x z)
      (* z x))     ; first here is x 7
     7
     (+ x y)))     ; this x is from the outer
 2
 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(let ((x 2) (y 3))
```

Here the 1st `let` is still in charge *until all values* have been bound.

```
  (let ((x 7) (z (+ x y)))
```

Here the 2nd `let` is in charge.

```
    (* z x)))
```

If you want `(x 7)` to be used in `(z (+ x y))` then try `let*`

**TEST**

```
(let ((x 2) (y 3))
  (let ((x 7) (z (+ x y)))
    (* z x)))

> 35

(let ((x 2) (y 3))
  (let* ((x 7) (z (+ x y)))
    (* z x)))

> 70
```

Hope it helps.